# How does liquefying fruit compare to eating them whole?

Tags: fruit

I peel my fruits, quarter them, then hurl  in my Vitamix blender. I don't filter or remove anything besides the rind. I'll call them liquefactions, as juice usually filters something.

I often can't eat whole fruit as scraps get stuck in my teeth, but I may not have the chance to floss and can't have scraps stuck in my teeth especially when I'm meeting clients!

How does liquefying fruit affect the flavor, sweetness, or other such properties?

Comment: Since you do this, it seems you would already know the answer to the question and should be informing us, not the other way around.

Comment: Haven't you asked this question before? Why again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/103795/27482

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blending peeled raw whole fruits (unfiltered) v. eating them whole?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/103795/blending-peeled-raw-whole-fruits-unfiltered-v-eating-them-whole)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flavor of juice will be more intense and sweeter than eating a fruit raw, and the mouth feel will obviously be very different.

A Vitamix will heat up the juice, and heat can change many properties of your juice, including flavor and nutrition. If you only blend for a short time this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, short quick blitzes work well. If you are using citrus fruits, and drinking it unfiltered, please keep two things in mind - it will turn bitter very quickly if you store it, and it will have roughage.